# Given 2 strings representing numbers as input, return the larger number. Note that both the numbers are non negative

Tags: java

```
Sample Input #1

larger("923","3243")

Sample Output #1

3243

Sample Input #2

larger("2354725234782357","2354725234782347")

Sample Output #2

2354725234782357
```

code

```
public String larger(String num1, String num2){

      String str1="";
      int a=Integer.parseInt(num1);
      int b=Integer.parseInt(num2);
      if(num1.length()>num2.length())
      return num1;
      if(num2.length()>num1.length())
      return num2;
      if(num1.length()==num2.length()){
      if(a>b){
      str1=""+a;
      return str1;
      }  
      }
      return str1+b;


   }
```

my code passes 1st test case but unable to pass other cases.what to do? withut using string functions.

```
Testcase    Pass/Fail   Parameters  Actual Output   Expected Output
#1  Pass    '1233456' '98765'   1233456     1233456
#2  Fail    '9283941233456' '23745237234298765'     null    23745237234298765
```

Comment: @SURESH ATTA what condition should i put ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading number as integer (given the number that you are trying to parse overflows the range of integer), read them as long like:

```
long a=Long.parseLong(num1);
long b=Long.parseLong(num2);
```

And then compare two long numbers to find out which one is biggest.

Comment: @SMA_ i know this function but it is strictly mentioned not to use string function or try to parse number in long.

Comment: @PallaviSingh: something that you *strictly* did **not** mention in your question. +1 to the answer, -1 to the question. Please fix your question.

Comment: @PallaviSingh: I did a search of your question and cannot find the word "long" anywhere to be found. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but please correct the question if I am right.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels _ Oh sorry my bad..btw thanxs for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Before converting or comparing, check your numbers shouldn't be overflown to int. Your values are causing integer overflow. Hence the unexpected results.

Check your input must in the range `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`. If you want to deal with big numbers than these, go for `long`'s

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare numbers with the following criteria:

- "Numbers are non negative"
- "Without using string functions"
- "Can't parse number in long" (from comment in SMA's answer)

That doesn't make any sense. If you receive the numbers as strings, you *have* to use some string functions to examine the value.

Given the first criteria, I believe what is meant is that you can't use any function that takes string as an argument. This eliminates `Integer.parseInt(String)`, `Long.parseLong(String)`, `new BigInteger(String)`, and so on.

Instead, your logic should be to compare the numbers "as strings". This basically means:

- Compare the string length. If different, the longer string is the larger number.
- For same length, a simple string compare will give you the "larger" number.

The above code assumes that numbers are not entered with leading zeros, e.g. `0003` would compare larger than `07`. I'll leave it up to you to try to figure out how to solve that, if it's an issue.